# What am i doing wrong with calling my method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, methods

I don't get it. i am a newbie to objective c and i just don't get what i am doing wrong here. I get the following error when building my code: **"Class method '+ValidateUserInfo:strPwd:'** not found ". I'm sure it's something simple for some of you out there and i just see my mistake. What is the correct way to call my method `ValidateUserInfo?`

```
@implementation LoginViewController

-(IBAction)CheckInfo:(id)sender
{
   NSString *strUserName = [[txtUsername text] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    NSString *strPass = [[txtPass text] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

   [LoginViewController ValidateUserInfo:strUserName myPass:strPass];
}

+(void)ValidateUserInfo:(NSString *)name myPass:(NSString*)strPwd
{
    NSLog(@"VALIDATE user: %@",name);
    NSLog(@"VALIDATE pwd: %@",strPwd);
}

@end
```

Comment: Methods don't start with a capital. Is the method declaration in the .h file?

Comment: That looks essentially correct.  Did you by chance declare the method differently in the .h?  Or is it possible that you've #defined "myPass" somewhere?

Comment: Methods *shouldn't* start with caps, to conform to standard Objective-C coding conventions.  Many do start with caps, however.

Comment: most of the code that i have seen in books have method names that are capitalized. i was used to the java naming standards and found it odd that all of the method names (so far) in my iOS 4 book are capitalized.

Comment: Yeah, I think one of the books I have capitalizes method names.  For your own personal use it doesn't matter much, though it's best to stick with one scheme.  If you will be sharing work with others it's important to have some semblance of "coding standards", though, and lower-cased methods (and upper-cased classes) is the "usual norm" for Objective-C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks fine, is it a compiler warning? if so it will be due to the fact that you don't declare the method in your header file (.h)...

Add the following before the `@end` in the header...

```
+(void)ValidateUserInfo:(NSString *)name myPass:(NSString*)strPwd;
```

Comment: this was all that i was missing. thanks a MILLION !!!!! i knew it had to be something simple but i was just not getting it. Thanks Simon !!!

Comment: I don't get it, in that case, shouldn't the error be *Class method `+ValidateUserInfo:myPass:` not found* instead?

Comment: that is the error irene?  i still think you should read up a little on those symbols -/+ sexi.  if your dont mean to have that be a "class method" than those symbols should be changed to - and it should be [self ValidateUserInfo:strUserName myPass:strPass];instead of  [LoginViewController ValidateUserInfo:strUserName myPass:strPass];

Comment: @Irene -- Yeah, it wasn't clear whether "strPwd:" was a tupo or what he was really seeing.  Added confusion.  **sexitrainer** -- it's really important to copy/paste the ACTUAL error messages, if at all possible -- a single character difference can be very significant.

Answer (score 1):

That error doesn't match your code sample. Are you sure this is the code that is giving you the error? Can you show the declaration of the method from the .h file?

Your error says a method called

```
ValidateUserInfo:strPwd
```

is not found, but your code calls and implements a method called

```
ValidateUserInfo:myPass.
```

Note also that method names should start with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `ValidateUserInfo:strPwd:` but according to your code it should be `ValidateUserInfo:myPass`!

Comment: He IS calling ValidateUserInfo:myPass:.....  [LoginViewController ValidateUserInfo:strUserName myPass:strPass]

Comment: You're right, thanks. But still, I don't get it; how can the error be about '+ValidateUserInfo:strPwd:' when the "strPwd" is just an argument name?

Comment: i don't get it either but declaring the method in the header file worked.

Comment: This shouldn't of been down voted. You can't assume the OP made a typo and then down vote someones answer...

Answer (score 0):

> +(plus sign) stands for class method as opposed to
>
> -(minus sign) which stands for an objects method

`-(void)` or `+(void)` are 2 very different things.  From the small snippet of code you gave I dont think ValidateUserInfo should be a "class" method

so.......

```
+(void)ValidateUserInfo:(NSString *)name myPass:(NSString*)strPwd
{
    NSLog(@"VALIDATE user: %@",name);
    NSLog(@"VALIDATE pwd: %@",strPwd);
}
```

should be

```
-(void)ValidateUserInfo:(NSString *)name myPass:(NSString*)strPwd
{
    NSLog(@"VALIDATE user: %@",name);
    NSLog(@"VALIDATE pwd: %@",strPwd);
}
```

Comment: You assume he didn't want a class method, however you didn't explain why his code (which SHOULD work) isn't...

Comment: i think its a fair assumption and even though it should work, it shouldnt be done without knowing why your doing it.  and further more a good piece of knowledge to someone who labelled themselves as a "newb"

Comment: Why would you want this to be an instance method? You want validation per login controller?

Comment: i can see that now.  as i thought of it more.  but my statement still stands.  if he doesnt know what these symbols mean its important knowledge to someone new

Answer (score 0):

Add to `+(void)ValidateUserInfo:(NSString *)name myPass:(NSString*)strPwd;` to `@interface LoginViewController` (better solution).

Or just put implementation of `+(void)ValidateUserInfo:(NSString *)name myPass:(NSString*)strPwd` before `-(IBAction)CheckInfo:(id)sender`.

Answer (score 0):

In your .h, make sure that you declare the method. example:

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController {

}

+(void)ValidateUserInfo:(NSString *)name myPass:(NSString*)strPwd;

@end

Also, as a side note, your method names should start lower case.

Answer (score -2):

Change:

```
[LoginViewController ValidateUserInfo:strUserName myPass:strPass];
```

to:

```
 [self ValidateUserInfo:strUserName myPass:strPass];
```

Comment: No, the method is a class method. (`+(void)...`)

Comment: Self is an instance as it is being called from an instance method (denoted by -), this won't work with ValidateUserInfo being a class method (denoted by the +).

Comment: Does it need to be a class method? It doesn't seem to, so he needs to change also:
+(void)ValidateUserInfo... to
-(void)ValidateUserInfo...

Comment: still get same warning. if i run the code, i will get the following message: -<font color='green'><b>[LoginViewController ValidateUserInfo:myPass:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c59050</b></font><br/><br/>
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[LoginViewController ValidateUserInfo:myPass:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c59050'

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Simon Lee and dasdom are right. It is obviously a class method.